# Infinityfree.net and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, hosting

Good Day!
I have this problem using infinityfree.net as my hosting site.
I used codeigniter framework for my code.
The problem is:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Login_model
```

My code working properly on xampp.

database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'HOSTNAME',
    'username' => 'USERNAME',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'DATABASE_NAME',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Here's my login_model.php

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
function login($par1,$par2){
     //CODE HERE
}
```

Here's my controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url', 'form');
    }
public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('login_model'); 
    }
```

PS. i didnt include much more code in controller because thats the only thing that has error and also Im unable to post too much code because of the rule of stackoverflow. Hoping you guys to help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: don't share your login credentials over the internet! The error says: *"Unable to locate the model you have specified: Login_model"*, have you uploaded the model in the right place? Did you follow the naming convention of Capitalized first letter of filenames and class names?

Comment: Sorry about my log in credentials @Vickel 
I uploaded the model in the right place and yes all of the names I used are correct

Answer (score 0):

Fixed
I just renamed my login_model to Login_model